# persist new entity onFlush

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to user the `onFlush` Event in Doctrine to persist a new entity, but it leads to an infinite loop when trying to persist. Here is what I do in the Listener:

```php
$countusers = $em->getRepository('DankeForumBundle:NotificationUser')->countNotificationsByDeal($entity);
if ($countusers > 0) {
  $notification = new NotificationAction();
  $notification->setDeal($entity);
  $notification->setDatepost(new \DateTime());
  $notification->setNotificationtype(NotificationAction::TYPE_TOP_DEAL);
  // $em is set to EntityManager
  $em->persist($notification);
  // $uow ist set to UnitOfWork
  $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassmetadata('Danke\ForumBundle\Entity\NotificationAction'), $notification);
}
```

I know that I would get a loop, when I was flushing in the `onFlush` Event, but I don't do that! I only compute the new change set as it says in the documentation.

Can someone tell where the problem is?

Answer (score 9):

I had similar issues with onFlush Event. Please change

```
$em->persist($notification);
```

to

```
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->persist($notification);

$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($notification));
$uow->computeChangeSet($metadata, $notification);
```

`$uow->persist()` will make the *UnitOfWork* know about the new entity and will schedule it for insertion.
Calling `$uow->computeChangeSet()` is neccessary, to collect the data that should be inserted by Doctrine's persister.