# Persist inside onFlush listener symfony

Tags: symfony, listener, persist

I'm trying to persist one entity inside onFlush listener...
This is my code:

```
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args){

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        switch (true) {
            case $entity instanceof Products:

                $changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

                foreach($changeset as $column => $change) {
                            $logs = new Logs();
                            $logs->setDate(new DateTime());


                            $em->persist($logs);
                            $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata('BddBundle:Logs');
                            $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $logs);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default : break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program block (no lines inserted into database) and PHP say:

PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in applis/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 653, referer: http://website/

Does anyone have a solution / way ?

Regards

EDIT 1:

Changing $em to $uow does not make any changes...

```
             $uow->persist($logs);
                    $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata('BddBundle:Logs');
                    $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $logs);
```

Comment: Compute the change set once, not inside the loop. This is madness, this is not Sparta. Why did you add that `switch(true)` anyway too lol, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [persist new entity onFlush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796496/persist-new-entity-onflush)

Comment: @emix : I just change the switch to if statement and now I persist only one time, but same problem...

Answer (score 2):

This watches the changes on `User` entity and inserts a bit of data into `UserLog` entity. Adjust it to your needs.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class UserEntityListener
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof User) {
                $userLog = new UserLog();
                $userLog->setUserId($entity->getId());
                $userLog->setMessage('onFlush - update at ' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));

                $em->persist($userLog);
                // Instead of $em->flush() because we are already in flush process
                $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($userLog)), $userLog);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't loop. I personally use exactly the same thing in my app. You might have a different problem in your app. Check this: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oymp/onflush-event-listener-on-an-entity

Comment: You can also check this http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ew0r/logging-field-changes-with-a-trigger-like-event-listener-for-auditing-purposes for checking the fields that has changed.

Comment: I check these link but I don't know why... It's always looping infinitly...

Comment: This example also works with Doctrine's ODM if you replace every instance of `entity` with `document`.